# Solving base class ambiguity for nested template parameter functions

Tags: c++, templates, inheritance, ambiguous

I have classes foo_impl, bar_impl deriving from derived classes foo_derived, bar_derived, and a function that takes in a templated template-parameter:

```
#include <iostream>
template <typename T>
struct foo_base
{
    T a;
};

template <typename T>
struct foo_derived: public foo_base<T>
{

};

struct foo_impl: public foo_derived<int>
{

};

template <typename T>
struct bar_base
{
    T a;
};

template <typename T>
struct bar_derived : public bar_base<T>
{
};

struct bar_impl : public bar_derived<int>
{
};

template <typename T, template <class> typename Base>
void useBase(const Base<T>& Arg)
{
    std::cout << Arg.a << std::endl;
}

int main()

{
    foo_impl foo;
    bar_impl bar;

    useBase(foo); // ‘const Base<T>’ is an ambiguous base class of ‘foo_impl’
    useBase(bar); // ‘const Base<T>’ is an ambiguous base class of ‘bar_impl’
}
```

Is it possible to specify that I want foo_base and bar_base to be the only types that can be passed to useBase(.)?

Edit: I tried introducing a concept in order to constrain the accepted types, but the compiler is still not happy.

```
template <typename T, template <class> typename Base>
concept is_base = !std::is_same<std::is_same<Base<T>, foo_base<T>>, std::is_same<Base<T>, bar_base<T>>>::value;

template <typename T, template <class> typename Base>
void useBase(const Base<T>& Arg) requires is_base<T, Base>
{
    std::cout << Arg.a << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: Is a c++20-only solution ok for you?

Comment: Yes, I've been looking at concepts, but haven't found a solution yet

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit on why you need `Base` in `useBase()`? Is it because you want to reinstantiate the same template with a different argument?

Comment: Overload usebase for foo_base and bar_base.

Comment: I'm using Eigen-expressions (which come in the shape of MatrixBase<T> and SparseMatrixBase<T>), and I'm trying to unify my methods for using combinations of both dense and sparse matrices

Comment: This code should already compile on a recent compiler: it seems that GCC 11 or Clang 12 suffices.

Comment: @BrianBi: It would compile indeed [Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/4o48vEeT5) but won't take OP's expected `Base` [Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/bbddd014f9461994).

Comment: I'm fine with C++20, but It would be nice to have a solution working with gcc 9.3.0.

Comment: As mentioned by @n.1.8e9-where's-my-sharem. it is possible to overload for the two types, but I have many occurences of this where the exact same implementation is needed.

Comment: @JonasHjulstad. So you want to prohibit the above two `useBase` from being called?

Comment: I want useBase(const foo_base<T>&) and useBase(const bar_base<T>&) to be the only allowed calls

Comment: You can factor out and call the common implementation.

Comment: Do you mean a struct-wrapper? I'm working on that kind of solution now, but since this problem is attached to linear algebra it appears in many different places, so it can get messy

Answer (score 0):

As state in comment, overloading might be a possibility:

```
template <typename T, template <class> typename Base>
void useBaseImpl(const Base<T>& Arg)
{
    std::cout << Arg.a << std::endl;
}

template <typename T>
void useBase(const foo_base<T>& arg)
{
    useBaseImpl(arg);
}

template <typename T>
void useBase(const bar_base<T>& arg)
{
    useBaseImpl(arg);
}
```